# Rails paginate like condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pagination

I want to filter my `paginate` returned values based on user input. But the user input is not always precise. So, instead of using a `=` comparison I have to use an `like`. My first attempt was

```
Person.paginate :page => params[:page], :conditions => ["name like '%?%'", entered_name]
```

but the resulting query was `where name like '%'my_user_input'%'`. And this is an invalid query.

The following query returns what I am trying to achieve, but it opens a breach for SQL Injection.

```
Person.paginate :page => params[:page], :conditions => ["name like '%#{entered_name}%'"]
```

Its resulting query is `where name like '%my_user_input%'`.

Question is: How can I use a like condition without creating this security issue?

I'm using rails 3.0.20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord supports a `matches` method on `Arel::Table` that handles escaping.

In your case you can use

```
Person.where(Person.arel_table[:name].matches("%#{params[:entered_name]}%")).
  paginate(page: params[:page])
```

and leave the security handling to ActiveRecord.